# link to a function in java script in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails
I am trying to generate an equivalent code for the following html tag in ruby on rails

```
<a href="javascript:show_calendar('document.tstest.timestamp', document.tstest.timestamp.value);"><img src="cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Click Here to Pick up the timestamp"></a>
```

Can any one please help me out.

Thank you

Comment: That HTML tag, as written, is perfectly valid "Ruby on Rails" (put it in one of your ERB views, and it will work just fine).

Comment: @user2163629, if it worked, would you consider voting up/accepting my answer? On SO, it's considered both helpful and polite to do so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet utilizes the Rails `image_tag` and `link_to` helper methods, but produces precisely equivalent markup to what you want:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag('cal.gif', :width => 16, :height => 16 :border => 0, :alt => "Click Here to Pick up the timestamp"), "javascript:show_calendar('document.tstest.timestamp', document.tstest.timestamp.value);") %>
#=> <a href="javascript:show_calendar('document.tstest.timestamp', document.tstest.timestamp.value);"><img alt="Click Here to Pick up the timestamp" border="0" height="16" src="/assets/cal.gif" width="16" /></a>
```